# Any way to "shortcut" common joins or code blocks in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have my tables in fairly normalized forms (I've only just started learning this, so I would wildly guess that I'm using 3rd normal form but I also know that I'm probably wrong, just as I know that some of my example code will be horribly written and also potentially wrong), and there are a few very common joins that I use across several queries.

For illustration's sake, let's say I have information on songs, something like this:

```
Songs:
song_id (PK) | song_title | first_artist | most_famous_artist

Albums:
album_id (PK) | album_title | version | format | year_released

Song versions:
song_version_id (PK) | song_id (FK) | artist | year_released

Album tracks:
album_id (PK, FK) | track_no (PK) | song_version_id (FK)
```

And suppose that I am frequently pulling up information on a particular version of a song, including the name of the song and the album it appeared on, so I keep writing:

```
FROM
 song_versions as sv
 INNER JOIN songs as s on sv.song_id = s.song_id
 INNER JOIN album_tracks as at on at.song_version_id = sv.song_version_id
 INNER JOIN albums as a on a.album_id = at.album_id
```

or whatever the case may be. I know I could denormalize a bit, and either combine a couple of tables together or have some data duplicated across tables and make sure I keep them consistent. But is there a way to keep the data structure the same, but have a shortcut to refer to the combination of song/version/album without having to write the same join all the time? (Especially if I may often want to only refer to particular subsets of that same join - e.g. the albums containing the most famous version of a particular song, or songs that have appeared on an album released after 2000.)

Comment: You can use [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-syntax.html)

Comment: You know, I thought I understood views, and then I tried referencing one and it didn't seem to work the way I expected. I'd be happy to learn that that was more a problem with how I wrote it, and that a view is exactly what I wanted in the first place. Maybe I'll try again, and if I can reproduce the problem I had with it I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Personally, I'd stick with what you've got

Comment: "my tables in fairly normalized forms... I would wildly guess that I'm using 3rd normal form" - You should be aiming for 5NF: the other normal forms are just for historical or academic interest e.g. BCNF was invented to fit between 3NF and 4NF because 3NF was wrongly specified, so why on earth would you aspire to 3NF!? :)

Comment: "I tried referencing [a `VIEW`] and it didn't seem to work the way I expected" - be aware "referencing" has a particular meaning in SQL: a foreign key "references" a key and therefore is the "referencing" element. I suspect you were doing something wrong or were being let down by a third party component because when your question is, "Surely there must be a way of reusing all these table joins?" then the answer is, "Of course, it is called a `VIEW`".